# While loop within sleep and retry the proccess

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a control file `file.txt` that always changes in value anytime depends on the other proccess.
The value of the file is like `1, 2, or 3`.

I want to execute my new job when the value of control file is `3`. So i need to check first the control file before do the execution job.

I was try `while loop` below using sleep for a moment and retry the proccess automatically every 5 seconds for 3 times, but the retry proccess is not running. How i resolved this?

```
#!/bin/bash
myname="kyy"

while read file; do
if [ $file == 2 ]; then
   
   echo "`date +%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S:%N` [ERROR]:-Value of Control File : $file "
   echo "`date +%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S:%N` [NOTICE]:-Nothing to do.. Script will exiting.." 

else

   echo "`date +%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S:%N` [SUCCESS]:-Go to next step "
   echo "`date +%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S:%N` [SUCCESS]:-My name is $myname "
fi
sleep 3
((c++)) && ((c==3)) && break
done < /home/hcuseros/file.txt
```

Comment: The loop is on the lines of the file... If you want to read the file 3 times, the "file parsing" has to be inside the loop.

Comment: Can you rewrite the script?

Comment: Can you pay me? :)
Since I suppose the answer is not. This is a good place to start with https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ :)

Comment: You will want to get rid of the [useless `echo`s.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) See also http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia I would generally avoid referring to the ABS which has a number of issues. The [Bash tag info page](/tags/bash/info) has a listing of learning resources near the end.

Comment: It's not clear what "retry process" you are referring to. Your script merely loops over the first three lines in the file. Should it read the first line three times? Then do what? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @tripleee I think ABS is covering quite well all the knowledge needed to solve the issue reported in this question. BTW, what are the issues you are referring to? (I read it about 15y ago and I was quite good at bash scripting at the time :) )

Comment: It is generally vague on recommendations vs opinions vs facts, and still sometimes contains errors or just misleading presentation.

Comment: `if [ -N $file ]` will evaluate to `true` if the file has changed since the last read

Comment: [How to execute a command whenever a file changes?](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simple way, where you only need to fill in your commands depending on the outcome of the test:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    file=$(cat test.txt)
    if [ $file -eq "3" ]; then
        ...
    else
        ...
    fi
    sleep 5
    done
```